# Keeping CMS history or not?

Tags: php, mysql, database, content-management-system

I have a database / systems question.
Say you have a CMS system done in PHP and Mysql

When you have users who edit their details, do you just update their row with the changes or do you keep a history for example by updating their row by setting the column 'status' = H (For History) and insert new row with all the old & new changed details with column 'status' = A (For Active) and that becomes the primary row?

I would just like to know what other developers do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd keep a history for audit purposes but I'd move old records to a history table to prevent problems with primary ids. I wouldn't keep old records in the same table as current, that's just too much redundant data.